# Export/Download a Google Document using Zend Gdata

Tags: php, google-data-api, zend-gdata

How do I export (i.e. Download it from Google to my local) a Google Document using the Zend Gdata class?

I can retrieve a list of all the documents easily enough with the Zend_Gdata_Docs methods:
getAllDocuments() and and getDocumentListFeed()

The examples given by Zend (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.docs.html) for the Google Document List Data API include an "Upload a Document" but not the corresponding "Download a Document"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok one way I was able to achieve this was by using:

Zend_Gdata method performHttpRequest()

The first param i passed was 'GET' and the second was the entry content URL ($entry->content->getSrc()) given by the previous getDocumentListFeed() call.

Not sure if there is a better way but that was like one or two lines of code...